# QRawFont/QPainterPath reproducing icon

Tags: c++, qt

I`m trying to reproduce an icon from FontAwesome.

First I load the font and get the points:

```
int fa = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf");
auto fas = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(fa).at(0);

QRawFont rfont = QRawFont::fromFont(fas);

qDebug() << rfont.pathForGlyph(0);
```

Result being:

```
QPainterPath: Element count=45
 -> MoveTo(x=10.5, y=-14)
 -> LineTo(x=1.5, y=-14)
 -> CurveTo(x=1.08333, y=-13.9792)
 -> CurveToData(x=0.729167, y=-13.8333)
 -> CurveToData(x=0.4375, y=-13.5625)
 -> CurveTo(x=0.166667, y=-13.2708)
 -> CurveToData(x=0.0208333, y=-12.9167)
 -> CurveToData(x=0, y=-12.5)
 -> LineTo(x=0, y=0.5)
 -> CurveTo(x=0.0208333, y=0.916667)
 -> CurveToData(x=0.166667, y=1.27083)
 -> CurveToData(x=0.4375, y=1.5625)
 -> CurveTo(x=0.729167, y=1.83333)
 -> CurveToData(x=1.08333, y=1.97917)
 -> CurveToData(x=1.5, y=2)
 -> LineTo(x=10.5, y=2)
 -> CurveTo(x=10.9167, y=1.97917)
 -> CurveToData(x=11.2708, y=1.83333)
 -> CurveToData(x=11.5625, y=1.5625)
 -> CurveTo(x=11.8333, y=1.27083)
 -> CurveToData(x=11.9792, y=0.916667)
 -> CurveToData(x=12, y=0.5)
 -> LineTo(x=12, y=-12.5)
 -> CurveTo(x=11.9792, y=-12.9167)
 -> CurveToData(x=11.8333, y=-13.2708)
 -> CurveToData(x=11.5625, y=-13.5625)
 -> CurveTo(x=11.2708, y=-13.8333)
 -> CurveToData(x=10.9167, y=-13.9792)
 -> CurveToData(x=10.5, y=-14)
 -> MoveTo(x=8.8125, y=-12)
 -> LineTo(x=6, y=-7.8125)
 -> LineTo(x=3.21875, y=-12)
 -> LineTo(x=8.8125, y=-12)
 -> MoveTo(x=2, y=-10.1875)
 -> LineTo(x=4.8125, y=-6)
 -> LineTo(x=2, y=-1.8125)
 -> LineTo(x=2, y=-10.1875)
 -> MoveTo(x=3.21875, y=0)
 -> LineTo(x=6, y=-4.1875)
 -> LineTo(x=8.8125, y=0)
 -> LineTo(x=3.21875, y=0)
 -> MoveTo(x=10, y=-1.8125)
 -> LineTo(x=7.21875, y=-6)
 -> LineTo(x=10, y=-10.1875)
 -> LineTo(x=10, y=-1.8125)
```

Then I am trying to reproduce it:

```
QPainterPath* polygonPath = new QPainterPath();

polygonPath->moveTo(10.5, -14);
polygonPath->lineTo(1.5, -14);
polygonPath->CurveTo(1.08333, -13.9792);
polygonPath->CurveToData(0.729167, -13.8333);
polygonPath->CurveToData(0.4375, -13.5625);
polygonPath->CurveTo(0.166667, -13.2708);
polygonPath->CurveToData(0.0208333, -12.9167);
polygonPath->CurveToData(0, -12.5);
polygonPath->lineTo(0, 0.5);
polygonPath->CurveTo(0.0208333, 0.916667);
polygonPath->CurveToData(0.166667, 1.27083);
polygonPath->CurveToData(0.4375, 1.5625);
polygonPath->CurveTo(0.729167, 1.83333);
polygonPath->CurveToData(1.08333, 1.97917);
polygonPath->CurveToData(1.5, 2);
polygonPath->lineTo(10.5, 2);
polygonPath->CurveTo(10.9167, 1.97917);
polygonPath->CurveToData(11.2708, 1.83333);
polygonPath->CurveToData(11.5625, 1.5625);
polygonPath->CurveTo(11.8333, 1.27083);
polygonPath->CurveToData(11.9792, 0.916667);
polygonPath->CurveToData(12, 0.5);
polygonPath->lineTo(12, -12.5);
polygonPath->CurveTo(11.9792, -12.9167);
polygonPath->CurveToData(11.8333, -13.2708);
polygonPath->CurveToData(11.5625, -13.5625);
polygonPath->CurveTo(11.2708, -13.8333);
polygonPath->CurveToData(10.9167, -13.9792);
polygonPath->CurveToData(10.5, -14);
polygonPath->moveTo(8.8125, -12);
polygonPath->lineTo(6, -7.8125);
polygonPath->lineTo(3.21875, -12);
polygonPath->lineTo(8.8125, -12);
polygonPath->moveTo(2, -10.1875);
polygonPath->lineTo(4.8125, -6);
polygonPath->lineTo(2, -1.8125);
polygonPath->lineTo(2, -10.1875);
polygonPath->moveTo(3.21875, 0);
polygonPath->lineTo(6, -4.1875);
polygonPath->lineTo(8.8125, 0);
polygonPath->lineTo(3.21875, 0);
polygonPath->moveTo(10, -1.8125);
polygonPath->lineTo(7.21875, -6);
polygonPath->lineTo(10, -10.1875);
polygonPath->lineTo(10, -1.8125);
polygonPath->closeSubpath();
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what to use instead of CurveTo and CurveToData. I have been reading the docs but just cannot understand it.

What I want to achieve is to obtain the icon points so I can draw it as a polygon. Similar to this:

```
QPolygon symbol;

symbol << QPoint(0.65, -9.75)
    << QPoint(5.85, -9.75)
    << QPoint(5.85, 0)
    << QPoint(0.65, 0);

painter.drawPolygon(symbol);
```

If someone would be so kind to provide a solution that would be amazing.

Comment: `CurveToData` is not an individual call. Instead it provides additional data which belongs to the recent `CurveTo`. I assume that way, the Qt guys handled to store function calls with varying number of arguments in an array or vector with (by definition) fix sized elements.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I see, honestly that's similar to what I imagined. Unfortunately I don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: I believe a `CurveTo` with two following `CurveToData` could be a [cubicTo()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#cubicTo). (and with one following `CurveToData` a [quadTo()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#quadTo)). With a small MCVE, you should be able to prove me right or wrong but I'm in good hope. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure whether the sequence of the points in `CurveTo`/`CurveToData` matches the order in the corresponding function calls. But even this should be verifiable by that small MCVE as well.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks, this is such a headache :) Looking at https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/painting/qpainterpath.cpp#n782 makes little to no sense to me. But I will certainly test.

Comment: Your link proves both of my guesses right (concerning `cubicTo()`). The `cubicTo()` is stored as `CurveTo, CurveToData, CurveToData` _and_ the order of arguments is preserved. The rest of the code just verifies that the passed arguments aren't invalid. - Concerning the `quadTo()`, I was wrong. It's converted into a `cubicTo()` call. If you ask yourself what `cubicTo()` actually does... It's a Bezier curve: [cubic-bezier](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat cubicTo, quadTo, you are speaking foreign language :) I will do my best to reproduce but if you have already in mind what's needed please post an answer :)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Just finished testing, and the out is: a line. Now I`m lost, please see: https://pastebin.com/DQGts1Jq

Comment: I will have a look at it later. (Sorry, I've to consider my real business.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Sure, I will keep playing with it. Just an FYI: https://forum.qt.io/topic/129803/drawing-custom-button-using-qpolygon/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [the other answer about QPainterPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73034283/7478597), I got the feedback that the actual issue of the OP seems to be to retrieve the painter path for the intended glyph.

Thus, I modified the MCVE to draw the painter path of a selected character.

First, I used the MS Character Table to chose a nice character:

[image: MS Character Table - Skull]

The relevant info is the Unicode code point shown in the bottom status line: `U+2620`.

Then I modified the `makeSample()` to use that character for retrieval of the corresponding painter path:

```
QPainterPath makeSample()
{
  // get a font which should be able to provide most of the Unicode code points
  QFont qFont("Arial Unicode MS");
  // transform font into a raw font
  QRawFont qRawFont = QRawFont::fromFont(qFont);
  // build a Qt string with the intended character
  QString qText(1, QChar(0x2620)); // 0x2620 is the Unicode code point for Skull
  // retrieve the glyph index for the character
  QVector<quint32> qGlyphIndices = qRawFont.glyphIndexesForString(qText);
  // build the Qt painter path
  QPainterPath qPainterPath;
  for (quint32 qGlyphIndex : qGlyphIndices) {
    qPainterPath += qRawFont.pathForGlyph(qGlyphIndex);
  }
  // done
  return qPainterPath;
}
```

The first result was a Chinese glyph until I realized that the glyph index has nothing to do with the Unicode code point. (I had used `0x2620` (the Unicode code point) as glyph index.) Thus, I introduced the conversion with [QRawFont::glyphIndexesForString()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrawfont.html#glyphIndexesForString).

Similar to what OP described, the next thing I got were some lines in the upper left corner. With a short glance onto the dumped lists, I realized that there are y coordinates in the dump with negative numbers i.e. rendered beyond the top border of my `Canvas` widget.

Hence, I tweaked the rendering a bit until I found it acceptable somehow.

The whole MCVE:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Canvas: public QWidget {

  private:
    QPainterPath *_pQPainterPath;

  public:
    explicit Canvas(QPainterPath* pQPainterPath, QWidget* pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent),
      _pQPainterPath(pQPainterPath)
    { }

  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent) override;
};

void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent)
{
  if (!_pQPainterPath) return;
  const QRectF qRect = _pQPainterPath->boundingRect();
  const qreal scale
    = std::min(width() / qRect.width(), height() / qRect.height());
  const QPointF center(0.5 * width(), 0.5 * height());
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  QPen qPen(Qt::blue);
  qPen.setCosmetic(true);
  qPainter.setPen(qPen);
  qPainter.translate(center);
  qPainter.scale(scale, scale);
  qPainter.translate(-qRect.center());
  qPainter.drawPath(*_pQPainterPath);
}

const char* toText(QPainterPath::ElementType type)
{
  static const char* const texts[] = {
    "MoveTo", "LineTo", "CurveTo", "CurveToData"
  };
  const size_t n = std::size(texts);
  return type < n ? texts[type] : "???";
}

QString list(const QPainterPath& qPainterPath)
{
  QString qText;
  QTextStream qOut(&qText);
  for (int i = 0, n = qPainterPath.elementCount(); i < n; ++i) {
    const QPainterPath::Element& qPPElem = qPainterPath.elementAt(i);
    qOut << toText(qPPElem.type) << "(x=" << qPPElem.x << ", y=" << qPPElem.y << ")\n";
  }
  return qText;
}

QString listSrc(const QPainterPath& qPainterPath)
{
  QString qText;
  QTextStream qOut(&qText);
  qOut << "QPainterPath qPainterPath;\n";
  for (int i = 0, n = qPainterPath.elementCount(); i < n; ++i) {
    const QPainterPath::Element& qPPElem = qPainterPath.elementAt(i);
    switch (qPPElem.type) {
      case QPainterPath::MoveToElement:
        qOut << "qPainterPath.moveTo(" << qPPElem.x << ", " << qPPElem.y << ");\n";
        break;
      case QPainterPath::LineToElement:
        qOut << "qPainterPath.lineTo(" << qPPElem.x << ", " << qPPElem.y << ");\n";
        break;
      case QPainterPath::CurveToElement: {
        if (i + 2 >= n
          || qPainterPath.elementAt(i + 1).type != QPainterPath::CurveToDataElement
          || qPainterPath.elementAt(i + 2).type != QPainterPath::CurveToDataElement) {
          qOut << "// BROKEN qPainterPath.cubicTo();\n";
          break; // ERROR!
        }
        const QPainterPath::Element& qPPElem1 = qPainterPath.elementAt(++i);
        const QPainterPath::Element& qPPElem2 = qPainterPath.elementAt(++i);
        qOut << "qPainterPath.cubicTo(" << qPPElem.x << ", " << qPPElem.y << ", "
           << qPPElem1.x << ", " << qPPElem1.y << ", "
           << qPPElem2.x << ", " << qPPElem2.y << ");\n";
      } break;
    }
  }
  return qText;
}

QPainterPath makeSample()
{
  QFont qFont("Arial Unicode MS");
  QRawFont qRawFont = QRawFont::fromFont(qFont);
  QString qText(1, QChar(0x2620)); // 0x2620 is the Unicode code point for Skull
  QVector<quint32> qGlyphIndices = qRawFont.glyphIndexesForString(qText);
  QPainterPath qPainterPath;
  for (quint32 qGlyphIndex : qGlyphIndices) {
    qPainterPath += qRawFont.pathForGlyph(qGlyphIndex);
  }
  return qPainterPath;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup data
  QPainterPath qPainterPath = makeSample();
  qDebug() << qPainterPath;
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Test QRawFont - QPainterPath");
  qWinMain.resize(480, 280);
  QSplitter qVSplit(Qt::Vertical);
  Canvas canvas(&qPainterPath);
  qVSplit.addWidget(&canvas);
  QSplitter qHSplit(Qt::Horizontal);
  QPlainTextEdit qEditCode;
  qEditCode.setPlainText(listSrc(qPainterPath));
  qHSplit.addWidget(&qEditCode);
  QPlainTextEdit qEditPath;
  qEditPath.setPlainText(list(qPainterPath));
  qHSplit.addWidget(&qEditPath);
  qVSplit.addWidget(&qHSplit);
  qVSplit.setSizes({ 100, 180 });
  qWinMain.setCentralWidget(&qVSplit);
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: Snapshot of testQRawFontQPainterPath]

There is for sure a similarity though the rendering might not be perfect.

[image: Snapshot of testQRawFontQPainterPath with Yellow Brush]

This is how it looks if a yellow brush is used with the blue pen.
(I had removed the brush while fiddling as the result didn't match my expectation until I added the `qPen.setCosmetic(true);`.)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much. Still learning QT. And still not drawing properly for me, but I guess this is because I`m trying to use Font Awesome and there be more to it. At least now I have a way to play around with it.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I used the wrong .ttf file... it works great! Thanks again for this amazing tool :)

Comment: @Mecanik I tweaked the rendering a bit further to center and scale the `QPainterPath` in the `Canvas`.

Comment: Many thanks! Do you have any idea how to "fill" the output? For example, I`m reproducing this: https://fontawesome.com/search?q=lock&m=free&s=solid%2Cbrands

Comment: It seems the answer is setBrush :)

Comment: @Mecanik Yes, you're correct. I checked it and updated the answer. It probably makes more sense to use equal pen and brush color. I used the colors with high contrast to illustrate what is caused by pen vs. brush.

Comment: Thanks, I`m nearly there. Just need to figure out the exact size for these "font awesome" because it looks a bit weird lol.

Comment: So one thing I found after countless test is that the "pen" breaks the output. Qt::NoPen is the solution for me. Second thing I noticed is that when I resize the output, it will look "broken". For example, I have a class specifically for buttons inheriting QAbstractButton which I resize to 18x18. This looks "ok" but does not match my needs so when I resize to 16x16 the image is well, broken. I wonder if this has something to do with the original font size points?

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that all the guessing in my comments could have been prevented as the doc. about `QPainterPath` mentions explicitly how it works:

> ### [enum QPainterPath::ElementType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#ElementType-enum)
>
> This enum describes the types of elements used to connect vertices in subpaths.
>
> Note that elements added as closed subpaths using the addEllipse(), addPath(), addPolygon(), addRect(), addRegion() and addText() convenience functions, is actually added to the path as a collection of separate elements using the moveTo(), lineTo() and cubicTo() functions.
>
> | *Constant* | *Value* | *Description* |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `QPainterPath::MoveToElement` | 0 | A new subpath. See also [moveTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#moveTo)(). |
> | `QPainterPath::LineToElement` | 1 | A line. See also [lineTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#lineTo)(). |
> | `QPainterPath::CurveToElement` | 2 | A curve. See also [cubicTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#cubicTo)() and [quadTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#quadTo)(). |
> | `QPainterPath::CurveToDataElement` | 3 | The extra data required to describe a curve in a CurveToElement element. |

I made my own MCVE to illustrate this:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Canvas: public QWidget {

  private:
    QPainterPath *_pQPainterPath;

  public:
    explicit Canvas(QPainterPath* pQPainterPath, QWidget* pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent),
      _pQPainterPath(pQPainterPath)
    { }

  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent) override;
};

void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent)
{
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  qPainter.setPen(
    QPen(
      QColor(79, 106, 25), 1,
      Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap, Qt::MiterJoin));
  qPainter.setBrush(QColor(122, 163, 39));
  if (_pQPainterPath) qPainter.drawPath(*_pQPainterPath);
}

const char* toText(QPainterPath::ElementType type)
{
  static const char* const texts[] = {
    "MoveTo", "LineTo", "CurveTo", "CurveToData"
  };
  const size_t n = std::size(texts);
  return type < n ? texts[type] : "???";
}

QString list(const QPainterPath& qPainterPath)
{
  QString qText;
  QTextStream qOut(&qText);
  for (int i = 0, n = qPainterPath.elementCount(); i < n; ++i) {
    const QPainterPath::Element& qPPElem = qPainterPath.elementAt(i);
    qOut << toText(qPPElem.type) << "(x=" << qPPElem.x << ", y=" << qPPElem.y << ")\n";
  }
  return qText;
}

QString listSrc(const QPainterPath& qPainterPath)
{
  QString qText;
  QTextStream qOut(&qText);
  qOut << "QPainterPath qPainterPath;\n";
  for (int i = 0, n = qPainterPath.elementCount(); i < n; ++i) {
    const QPainterPath::Element& qPPElem = qPainterPath.elementAt(i);
    switch (qPPElem.type) {
      case QPainterPath::MoveToElement:
        qOut << "qPainterPath.moveTo(" << qPPElem.x << ", " << qPPElem.y << ");\n";
        break;
      case QPainterPath::LineToElement:
        qOut << "qPainterPath.lineTo(" << qPPElem.x << ", " << qPPElem.y << ");\n";
        break;
      case QPainterPath::CurveToElement: {

        if (i + 2 >= n
          || qPainterPath.elementAt(i + 1).type != QPainterPath::CurveToDataElement
          || qPainterPath.elementAt(i + 2).type != QPainterPath::CurveToDataElement) {
          qOut << "// BROKEN qPainterPath.cubicTo();\n";
          break; // ERROR!
        }
        const QPainterPath::Element& qPPElem1 = qPainterPath.elementAt(++i);
        const QPainterPath::Element& qPPElem2 = qPainterPath.elementAt(++i);
        qOut << "qPainterPath.cubicTo(" << qPPElem.x << ", " << qPPElem.y << ", "
           << qPPElem1.x << ", " << qPPElem1.y << ", "
           << qPPElem2.x << ", " << qPPElem2.y << ");\n";
      } break;
    }
  }
  return qText;
}

QPainterPath makeSample()
{
#if 0 // ORIGINAL:
  // taken from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#details
  QPainterPath qPainterPath;
  qPainterPath.addRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
  qPainterPath.moveTo(0, 0);
  qPainterPath.cubicTo(99, 0,  50, 50,  99, 99);
  qPainterPath.cubicTo(0, 99,  50, 50,  0, 0);
#else // DUMPED in listSrc:
  QPainterPath qPainterPath;
  qPainterPath.moveTo(20, 20);
  qPainterPath.lineTo(80, 20);
  qPainterPath.lineTo(80, 80);
  qPainterPath.lineTo(20, 80);
  qPainterPath.lineTo(20, 20);
  qPainterPath.moveTo(0, 0);
  qPainterPath.cubicTo(99, 0, 50, 50, 99, 99);
  qPainterPath.cubicTo(0, 99, 50, 50, 0, 0);
#endif // 0
  return qPainterPath;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup data
  QPainterPath qPainterPath = makeSample();
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Test QPainterPath");
  qWinMain.resize(480, 280);
  QSplitter qVSplit(Qt::Vertical);
  Canvas canvas(&qPainterPath);
  qVSplit.addWidget(&canvas);
  QSplitter qHSplit(Qt::Horizontal);
  QPlainTextEdit qEditCode;
  qEditCode.setPlainText(listSrc(qPainterPath));
  qHSplit.addWidget(&qEditCode);
  QPlainTextEdit qEditPath;
  qEditPath.setPlainText(list(qPainterPath));
  qHSplit.addWidget(&qEditPath);
  qVSplit.addWidget(&qHSplit);
  qVSplit.setSizes({ 100, 180 });
  qWinMain.setCentralWidget(&qVSplit);
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.15.1
QPainterPath: Element count=12
 -> MoveTo(x=20, y=20)
 -> LineTo(x=80, y=20)
 -> LineTo(x=80, y=80)
 -> LineTo(x=20, y=80)
 -> LineTo(x=20, y=20)
 -> MoveTo(x=0, y=0)
 -> CurveTo(x=99, y=0)
 -> CurveToData(x=50, y=50)
 -> CurveToData(x=99, y=99)
 -> CurveTo(x=0, y=99)
 -> CurveToData(x=50, y=50)
 -> CurveToData(x=0, y=0)
```

[image: Snapshot of testQPainterPath (Original)]

This is the output for the original sample (taken from Qt doc.).

[image: Snapshot of testQPainterPath (Dumped)]

This is the output for the source code dumped in the lower left text view and copied into the source.

(Some kind of [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers))? ;-))

Comment: This is really nice, thank you. I have played around with the code since then and I`m afraid there might be other stuff I did not consider. No matter which index I tried to use in pathForGlyph(), no matter what points I got, it always draws a "line" for me. In your example, you already have the points from the example, in my case I also need to get the right points (from a font, or an image/icon).